# Product of numbers with tail-recursive predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog, product, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a tail-recursive predicate in Prolog: `product(A,B)`, which is true if `B` is the product of the numbers in list `A`. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
product(A, B) :- product(A, 1, B).
product(0, B, B) :- !.
product(A, X, B) :- Z is A - 1, Y is X * A, product(Z, Y, B).
```

The code works without a list. I'm pretty new to lists in Prolog, so I want to ask what is the best way to do this. The query should be something like this:

```
?- product([1,2,3], B).
B = 6.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like that

```
product(In, Out) :-
    % We call the predicate product/3, initialize with 1 
    product(In, 1, Out).

% when the list is empty with have the result
product([], Out, Out).

% we compute the first element of the list
product([H|T], Cur, Out) :-
    Next is Cur * H,
    % we carry on with the rest
    product(T, Next, Out).
```

**EDIT**
Product not tail recursive.

```
product1([], 1).

product1([H|T],Out) :-
    product1(T, Next),
    Out is Next * H.
```

Comment: THX a lot! Is it tail-recursive?

Comment: Yes it is. I edit my answer. See the difference (using trace/0) with another code which is not tail-recursive